# HTML 5 canvas keydown event animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

So I'm fairly new to programming and I've been playing a bit around with HTML 5 and canvas. I've been trying to get a simple rectangle to move when pressing down a key, but I simply can't get i to work. I've followed this guide: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/JS/html5_canvas_keyboard_keys.html

Here's my code:
 HTML:
    
    
    
        CanvasTest

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TestStyle.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="TestApp.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="500"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var main = function (){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, true);

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 15);

    var x = 30;
    var y = 30;

    function doKeyDown(key) {
        alert (key.keyCode)

        if (key.keyCode == 87) { //w
            clearCanvas();
            y = y - 10;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 15)
        }
        if (key.keyCode == 83) { //s
            clearCanvas();
            y = y + 10;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 15)
        }
        if (key.keyCode == 65) { //a
            clearCanvas();
            y = x - 10;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 15)
        }
        if (key.keyCode == 68) { //d
            clearCanvas();
            y = x + 10;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"
            ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 15)
        }
    }

    function clearCanvas() {
        canvas.width = canvas.width;
    }
};  

$(document).ready(main);
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

When I load it up I get the canvas and the rectangle is displayed, yet I am not able to move the rectangle with WASD

Comment: remove the var from "var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");", this will make it global (Tip: check the javascript console in chome ctrl+shift+j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put comments to show you the changes in place.

I don't feel i need to explain much with very few changes but I have added comments to point them out.

> **Additional:** Auto focus & focus outline remove (*See comments in source code*)

```js
var main = function (){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, true);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255,.5)";
//_______________________________^ .5 = 50%/Half Alpha
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 15);
//----- Optional auto focus -------
//If you want the page to focus on your canva
canvas.focus();
var x = 30;
var y = 30;
function doKeyDown(key) {
if (key.keyCode == 87) { //w
   clearCanvas();
    y = y - 10;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255,.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 15);
}
if (key.keyCode == 83) { //s
    clearCanvas();
    y = y + 10;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255,.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 15);
}
if (key.keyCode == 65) { //a
    clearCanvas();
    x = x - 10; //Move Left -10 from x-axis
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255,.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 15);
}
if (key.keyCode == 68) { //d
    clearCanvas();
    x = x + 10; //Move right +10 from x-axis
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255,.5)";
    //__________________________________^ Close ;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 15);
}
}
function clearCanvas() {
canvas.width = canvas.width;
}
};  

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
canvas {
border: 1px solid #ddd;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
padding-top: 0;
display: block;
/*------ Remove outline on focus*/
/*outline: 0;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" tabindex="0"></canvas>
 <!--_________________________________________^^^^^ Missing tabindex -->
```

I hope this helps. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

On second evaluation, I have found some more error

I made a crude moving example (most important changes in code)

http://jsfiddle.net/zfbukakc/2/

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
window.addEventListener("keydown", doKeyDown, true);
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
x = 30;
y = 30;
```

The main issue seems to be variable scope check http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Will explain further in detail when I got some time later